# How to format string without leading zeros and + - as integer in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have rows in a column with strings in a pandas dataframe that look like this:

```
+0094
-0082
```

How would I replace all the values in the column so that they would be formatted like this:

```
 94
-82
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) as it provides more flexibility over `.astype` :

```py
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is smart enough to figure it out with a dataframe's `astype` method.

So your approach would be:

```py
df['col of interest'] = df['col of interest'].astype(int)
```